# How to update a multiselect menu in Bokeh

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh and I am trying without success to update a multiselect menu based on the user previous choice in another multiselect menu. No error is given but the 'set' menu is not updated in the code below based on the choice made in the 'species' menu. I have probably fumbled the last callback (lines 142-146) but I dont how to fix it. Thoughts ?

````
# Data handling
import pandas as pd

# Bokeh libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Toggle, ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, Callback, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, NumberFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, MultiSelect

# test data
original_data = dict(species = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','C','D','E','A','A'],
length = [2, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 70, 50, 15, 36, 76, 74, 72, 44, 36, 18, 40, 64, 40, 64, 40, 30, 120],
weight = [2, 100, 150, 200, 420, 700, 600, 300, 200, 200, 620, 610, 601, 610, 601, 80, 205, 80, 800, 700, 240, 160, 800],
set_number = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '5', '1'],
sex_id = [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2])

original_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
original_data['color'] = 'black'

original_source = ColumnDataSource(original_data)

# Empty source so the plot is empty before the data is selected
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(species = [], set_number = [], length = [], weight = [], sex_id = [], color = []))

### Main plot
plot = figure(title = 'Length-weight scatterplot', x_axis_label = 'length (cm)', y_axis_label = 'weight (g)',
        tools = "pan, hover, box_zoom, reset, save", toolbar_location = "right", 
        plot_width = 450, plot_height = 450)

plot.circle(x = 'length', y = 'weight', color = 'color', fill_alpha = 1, source = source, line_width = 2)

# Select species
available_species = list(set(original_data['species']))
available_species.sort()

species_callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'original_source': original_source},
code = """
var data = original_source.data;
var source_data = source.data;

var species_data = data['species'];
var length_data = data['length'];
var weight_data = data['weight'];
var sex_id_data = data['sex_id'];
var set_number_data = data['set_number'];
var color_data = data['color'];
var selected_species = cb_obj.value;

var source_length = source_data['length'];
source_length.length = 0;

var source_weight = source_data['weight'];
source_weight.length = 0;

var source_sex_id = source_data['sex_id'];
source_sex_id.length = 0;

var source_species = source_data['species'];
source_species.length = 0;

var source_set_number = source_data['set_number'];
source_set_number.length = 0;

var source_color = source_data['color'];
source_color.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < length_data.length; i++) {
if (selected_species.indexOf(species_data[i]) >= 0) 
source_length.push(length_data[i]);
source_weight.push(weight_data[i]);
source_species.push(species_data[i]);
source_set_number.push(set_number_data[i]);
source_sex_id.push(sex_id_data[i]);
source_color.push(color_data[i]);
}
}
source.change.emit();
""")

multiselect_species = MultiSelect(title = 'Species:', value = [], options = available_species, width = 240)
#multiselect_species.js_on_change('value', species_callback)

# Select set (multiselect)
#available_set = list(set(map(str, original_data['set_number'])))
available_set = list(set(original_data['set_number']))
available_set.sort()

set_callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'original_source': original_source},
code = """
var data = original_source.data;
var source_data = source.data;

var species_data = data['species'];
var length_data = data['length'];
var weight_data = data['weight'];
var sex_id_data = data['sex_id'];
var set_number_data = data['set_number'];
var color_data = data['color'];
var selected_species = cb_obj.value;

var source_length = source_data['length'];
source_length.length = 0;

var source_weight = source_data['weight'];
source_weight.length = 0;

var source_sex_id = source_data['sex_id'];
source_sex_id.length = 0;

var source_species = source_data['species'];
source_species.length = 0;

var source_set_number = source_data['set_number'];
source_set_number.length = 0;

var source_color = source_data['color'];
source_color.length = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < length_data.length; i++) {
 if (selected_species.indexOf(set_number_data[i]) >= 0) {

 source_length.push(length_data[i]);
 source_weight.push(weight_data[i]);
 source_species.push(species_data[i]);
 source_set_number.push(set_number_data[i]);
 source_sex_id.push(sex_id_data[i]);
 source_color.push(color_data[i]);
 }
 }
 source.change.emit();
 """)

multiselect_set = MultiSelect(title = 'Set:', value = [], options = available_set, width = 240)
multiselect_set.js_on_change('value', set_callback)

# The sets available should be updated depending on the species chosen
multiselect_species.js_on_change('value', species_callback, CustomJS(args = dict(multiselect_set = multiselect_set,
                                                                                  available_set = available_set),
code = """
const var_set = %s
multiselect_set.options = var_set.[cb_obj.value]
multiselect_set.options = multiselect_set.options.join()
""" % available_set))

# Data table
columns = [TableColumn(field = "species", title = "common name", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "set_number", title = "set number", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "length", title = "length (cm)", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "weight", title = "weight (g)", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "sex_id", title = "sex", width = 100)]

data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, sortable = True, editable = True, width = 500, height = 450,
                        fit_columns = True)

# Set up widgets layout
widgets_layout = column(multiselect_species, multiselect_set)

# Set up figures layout
figures_layout = row(plot, data_table)

# Set up page layout
page_layout = row(widgets_layout, figures_layout)

show(page_layout)


```I
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there was no Python error, but there were two JavaScript(JS) **syntax** errors in your code. Always look in the JS console in the browser if there are JS errors. You have also put a double callback for your `multiselect_species` (I removed the second one which was clearing your options). Below you have a working code for Bokeh v1.3.0

```
# Data handling
import pandas as pd

# Bokeh libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Toggle, ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, Callback, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, NumberFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, MultiSelect

# test data
original_data = dict(species = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','C','D','E','A','A'],
length = [2, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 70, 50, 15, 36, 76, 74, 72, 44, 36, 18, 40, 64, 40, 64, 40, 30, 120],
weight = [2, 100, 150, 200, 420, 700, 600, 300, 200, 200, 620, 610, 601, 610, 601, 80, 205, 80, 800, 700, 240, 160, 800],
set_number = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '5', '1'],
sex_id = [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2])

original_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
original_data['color'] = 'black'

original_source = ColumnDataSource(original_data)

# Empty source so the plot is empty before the data is selected
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(species = [], set_number = [], length = [], weight = [], sex_id = [], color = []))

### Main plot
plot = figure(title = 'Length-weight scatterplot', x_axis_label = 'length (cm)', y_axis_label = 'weight (g)',
        tools = "pan, hover, box_zoom, reset, save", toolbar_location = "right", 
        plot_width = 450, plot_height = 450)

plot.circle(x = 'length', y = 'weight', color = 'color', fill_alpha = 1, source = source, line_width = 2)

# Select species
available_species = list(set(original_data['species']))
available_species.sort()

code = """ 
    var data = original_source.data;
    var source_data = source.data;

    var species_data = data['species'];
    var length_data = data['length'];
    var weight_data = data['weight'];
    var sex_id_data = data['sex_id'];
    var set_number_data = data['set_number'];
    var color_data = data['color'];
    var selected_species = cb_obj.value;

    var source_length = source_data['length'];
    source_length.length = 0;

    var source_weight = source_data['weight'];
    source_weight.length = 0;

    var source_sex_id = source_data['sex_id'];
    source_sex_id.length = 0;

    var source_species = source_data['species'];
    source_species.length = 0;

    var source_set_number = source_data['set_number'];
    source_set_number.length = 0;

    var source_color = source_data['color'];
    source_color.length = 0;
    unique_sets = []
    for (var i = 0; i < length_data.length; i++) {
        if (selected_species.indexOf(species_data[i]) >= 0)  {
            source_length.push(length_data[i]);
            source_weight.push(weight_data[i]);
            source_species.push(species_data[i]);
            source_set_number.push(set_number_data[i]);
            source_sex_id.push(sex_id_data[i]);
            source_color.push(color_data[i]);

            if ( !unique_sets.includes(set_number_data[i]) ) {
                unique_sets.push(set_number_data[i])
            }
        }
    }

    source.change.emit();
    multiselect_set.options = unique_sets
"""

print(source.data['set_number'])

# species_callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 
#                                     'original_source': original_source,
#                                     'multiselect_set': multiselect_set,
#                                     },
#                             code = code)

multiselect_species = MultiSelect(title = 'Species:', value = [], options = available_species, width = 240)
#multiselect_species.js_on_change('value', species_callback)

# Select set (multiselect)
#available_set = list(set(map(str, original_data['set_number'])))
available_set = list(set(original_data['set_number']))
available_set.sort()

set_callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 'original_source': original_source},
code = """
var data = original_source.data;
var source_data = source.data;

var species_data = data['species'];
var length_data = data['length'];
var weight_data = data['weight'];
var sex_id_data = data['sex_id'];
var set_number_data = data['set_number'];
var color_data = data['color'];
var selected_species = cb_obj.value;

var source_length = source_data['length'];
source_length.length = 0;

var source_weight = source_data['weight'];
source_weight.length = 0;

var source_sex_id = source_data['sex_id'];
source_sex_id.length = 0;

var source_species = source_data['species'];
source_species.length = 0;

var source_set_number = source_data['set_number'];
source_set_number.length = 0;

var source_color = source_data['color'];
source_color.length = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < length_data.length; i++) {
     if (selected_species.indexOf(set_number_data[i]) >= 0) { 
         source_length.push(length_data[i]);
         source_weight.push(weight_data[i]);
         source_species.push(species_data[i]);
         source_set_number.push(set_number_data[i]);
         source_sex_id.push(sex_id_data[i]);
         source_color.push(color_data[i]);
     }
 }
 source.change.emit();
 """)

multiselect_set = MultiSelect(title = 'Set:', value = [], options = available_set, width = 240)
multiselect_set.js_on_change('value', set_callback)


species_callback = CustomJS(args = {'source': source, 
                                    'original_source': original_source,
                                    'multiselect_set': multiselect_set,
                                    },
                            code = code)

# The sets available should be updated depending on the species chosen
multiselect_species.js_on_change('value', species_callback)

# Data table
columns = [TableColumn(field = "species", title = "common name", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "set_number", title = "set number", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "length", title = "length (cm)", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "weight", title = "weight (g)", width = 100),
           TableColumn(field = "sex_id", title = "sex", width = 100)]

data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, sortable = True, editable = True, width = 500, height = 450,
                        fit_columns = True)

# Set up widgets layout
widgets_layout = column(multiselect_species, multiselect_set)

# Set up figures layout
figures_layout = row(plot, data_table)

# Set up page layout
page_layout = row(widgets_layout, figures_layout)

show(page_layout)
```